# R: How do I make a summary table with aggregate and non-aggregate information?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm working with the bigmart [data set](https://datahack.analyticsvidhya.com/contest/practice-problem-big-mart-sales-iii/). It has hypothetical data on sales figures for ten stores.

I want to make a table that shows each store, their total sales, average price and store type/age/size.

I used this code to add the aggregate information

```
xy <- group_by(train, Outlet_Identifier) %>% 
  summarize(sales = sum(Item_Outlet_Sales), 
            avgmrp = median(Item_MRP)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(sales))
```

and I made a table for the size of each outlet with this

```
table(Outlet_Identifier,Outlet_Size)
```

This is what the data looks like

```
   Outlet_Identifier    sales avgmrp
   <fct>                <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 OUT027            3453926.   144.
 2 OUT035            2268123.   146.
 3 OUT049            2183970.   142.
 4 OUT017            2167465.   141.
 5 OUT013            2142664.   142.
 6 OUT046            2118395.   144.
 7 OUT045            2036725.   142.
 8 OUT018            1851823.   141.
 9 OUT010             188340.   144.
10 OUT019             179694.   144.

                 Outlet_Size
Outlet_Identifier     High Medium Small
           OUT010 555    0      0     0
           OUT013   0  932      0     0
           OUT017 926    0      0     0
           OUT018   0    0    928     0
           OUT019   0    0      0   528
           OUT027   0    0    935     0
           OUT035   0    0      0   930
           OUT045 929    0      0     0
           OUT046   0    0      0   930
           OUT049   0    0    930     0
```

How do I make a summary table // add non-aggregate information to a command that uses summarize?

Edit: this is my desired output

```
   Outlet_Identifier    sales avgmrp    type         size
   <fct>                <dbl>  <dbl>    <  >         <  >
 1 OUT027            3453926.   144.    grocery       934
 2 OUT035            2268123.   146.    grocery       564
 3 OUT049            2183970.   142.    grocery       934
 4 OUT017            2167465.   141.    supermarket   874
 5 OUT013            2142664.   142.    grocery       356
 6 OUT046            2118395.   144.    supermarket   764
 7 OUT045            2036725.   142.    grocery       934
 8 OUT018            1851823.   141.    supermarket   634
 9 OUT010             188340.   144.    supermarket   334
10 OUT019             179694.   144.    grocery       343
```

Comment: Do you want the same output as `table` output with `tidyverse`

Comment: I want the output from xy with an extra column for the non-aggregate data. Like, one column for size and one for type and so on.

Comment: Not clear about the expected output

Comment: Have you tried `unique()`?

Comment: Where is the info about classifying it to `type` ?

Comment: I grabbed type since it is one of the variables. Same idea as size.

Comment: Would be better if you could `dput` an extract of the dataset so that we could test & check before posting, but I think some use of `group_by`,`summarise` and `left_join` is all you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to pass "type" column to some aggregating function and for size column you can use `n()` function.

```
train %>%
  group_by(Outlet_Identifier) %>%
  summarise(
    sales = sum(Item_Outlet_Sales),
    avgmrp = median(Item_MRP),
    type = min(Outlet_Type),
    size = n()
  ) %>%
  arrange(desc(sales))
```